# Mixed numbers and strings in pandas showing errors in Excel

Tags: python-3.x

We have an input field on a form that we send out that allows potential customers to enter in the number of employees that they have at their place.  Unfortunately, I'm not in control of the form itself, so I can't change that.

Anyway, sometimes people enter in a specific number (e.g. "100").  Other times people will enter in something like "about 50" or "45-50."

When I process this data in Pandas and then export it to Excel, Excel shows this as an error because there is numeric data mixed in with text data.

How do I prevent this?

So far I've tried:

the following function:

```
def make_numeric_into_string(text):
    if text.isnumeric():
        return "'" + str(text)
    else:
        return text
```

and formatting the column in Pandas:

```
df['People'] = df['People'].astype(str)
```

I have also played around with formatting the Excel column from Python, but I can't get it to stop showing the error.

There has to be a simple way to accomplish this that I am just unaware of.

update:

I discovered that a user had entered in an apostrophe.  Upon doing some Google searching, I came across some ways of handling this, but none seem to work.  Since it is a string that will be read by a human, I don't really care if a user enters "50."  I just want Excel to open.  So I tried this:

```
def add_escape_characters(text):
    escape_char_list = {'-', '"'}
    for escape_char in escape_char_list:
        if escape_char in text:
            # escape_char_index = text.index(escape_char)
            escaped_text = text.replace(escape_char, '\\' + escape_char)
            return escaped_text
        else:
            return text
```

However, it still gives me the errors in Excel.  Is there a clean way to remove special characters from strings in Python?

Comment: Could you show us the error traceback?

Comment: It's showing as an error in Excel, not in Python.  I'm not sure how to get more error information out of Excel.

Comment: It seems your function takes an argument and returns a string if it is not numeric and an integer if it is. Did you want that?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure.  I was trying to get the function to return a string if the input was a string, and convert it to a string if the input is numeric.  But, this was the latest iteration from different things that I've tried from googling similar issues.  To be honest, I'm stuck, so I'm not sure what the function should return or if a function should be used at all.

Comment: Um, does it do anything special after it's been formatted into Excel? If it does, then you should fix the function that handles the input from the cell. If not, then this should be fine... Is there a way to force a specific type on a cell?

Comment: Ok, I'll check that.  I just wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious.  But even when I manually in Excel change the type in Excel, it still gives me the error.  Like I said, though, I'll look into it further on the Excel side. Thanks for your input.